Excessively slow to connect to Milvus server from PyMilvus
It takes about 3-4 minutes to connect to my database via PyMilivus, whereas it is basically instantaneous via Attu and milvus_cli. What could be causing this?
Here's my code:
from pymilvus import connections, Collection

def get_collection(host, port, collection_name):
  """Create table
  input: host milvus database IP string,
  port milvus database port string,
  name table name string,
  description table description string,
  fields column name and type
  """
  connections.connect("default", host=host, port=port)
  collection = Collection(collection_name)
  collection.load()
  return collection

connections.connect("default", host=host, port=port)

